# $routeProvider does not route

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to redirect the url using the $routeprovider

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'scripts/login/login.tpl.html',
            controller : 'LoginCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider. when('/sample', {
      templateUrl: 'sample.html'
    });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo : '404.html'
        });
```

Below is the url which loads the application

```
http://localhost:8080/orion-web/app/
```

when I try to append the word 'sample' to the url 
ie

```
http://localhost:8080/orion-web/app/sample
```

I get 404 error , This is not the 404.html from the $routeprovider. It's tomcats 404 resource not found page

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a base url set for your page?

It should be <base href="/orion-web/app/"> within the header section of your index.html

Comment: It was commented out by someone, I uncommented it but issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

In the second $routeprovider.when try removing /

```
$routeProvider. when('sample', {
  templateUrl: 'sample.html'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'scripts/login/login.tpl.html',
            controller : 'LoginCtrl'
        })
    . when('/sample', {
      templateUrl: 'sample.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '404.html'
        });
```

Use this code

Comment: ManojMeria I tried your code without the semicolon and the result was the same

Comment: then scripts/login/login.tpl.html and sample.html file path wrong                                      fo more detail https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: yeah the resource was not in the right location. But even after giving the right paths , The issue is still there